# adding some domains to /etc/hosts constantly

Tags: ubuntu, unix, hosts-file

I've added some local domains to my `/etc/hosts` on Ubuntu. But it rewrites it every time I reboot OS.

How and where can I add constantly my `127.0.0.1  mydomain.local`?

**UPD**

Before reboot I edit `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost  mydomain.local
```

After reboot

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       hostname.domain.local hostname localhost
```

Also, put your hostname in `/etc/hostname`

If some other program (like networkmanager) keeps changing your hostfile, you could make it imutable.

```
chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

Comment: yep it looks okey, but it will be rewrited automatically to default after rebooting, so all my edits will be removed

Comment: Does it revert to 'localhost'?

Comment: it reverts `127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost`

Comment: Actually putting `mydomain.local` to `/etc/hostname` helps. Now `/etc/hosts` still rewrites but it adds `mydomain.local` to `::1 ... ` line. Thanx!

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a bug in Ubuntu NetworkManager and there is a workaround which is [**detailed in this document**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/659872).

Answer (score 1):

Probably is because of NetworkManager. Did you tried

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

after modifications ? If is still not working try to remove write attribute from /etc/hosts.

```
sudo chmod -w /etc/hosts
```

Regards